# Know in Contact after - insert, if the contact is created from regular input or lead convert

Tags: lead-conversion

I have this use case, where I need to know in the after-insert of a contact, whether the contact has been created from regular input  (or via API, doesn't matter), or if the contact was created via a Lead Convert.

There is no option of overriding the Convert page for Leads, as some leads are also converted via Salesforce1 or via the API.

Wondering if this is even possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I just got a solution from [Chris Edwards on twitter](https://twitter.com/Chris_SFDC/status/687277543465025536) (credits to him)*

Create 2 custom fields both Checkboxes on Contact and on Lead, the one on lead is default checked (true), the one on contact is default unchecked (false), and map them in the Lead Convert mapping.

Then in the triggers, you can use that field to check whether a contact is created from a lead convert or directly.